# Define dataType of column that is really big SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have data greater to this number, if I attempt to get several sums of them like::

`1,22826520941614E+24+1,357898350941614E+34+1,228367878888764E+26` I get as Result `NULL`, How to define the table Datatype for that kind of fields??

I am using float, but it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [float](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173773.aspx) is sufficiently large to contain data of that range. It can store binary floating-point values from -1.79E+308 to 1.79E+308. I suspect an error elsewhere in your statement.

Comment: mmm, in a result, for really large sums, and multiplications, I am getting NULL, what could be the problem???, like summing 16000, times that values

Comment: Please post your calculation code. As written in your question, I get the right answer, with SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting NULL back, it's not the data type. It's because you have a null value in one of the rows of data. NULL + anything is NULL.

Change your Sum() to include a WHERE YourNumericColumn IS NOT NULL, or use COALESCE().

Comment: btw, sum() ignores nulls, therefore COALESCE(SUM(YourNumericColumn ),0) is a better way